# how to get the array count if string is empty from nsdictionary?

Tags: swift

this is my respone

```
{

    activeFromDate = "01/01/2017";
    terminateDate = “02/05/2019”;

}

{

    activeFromDate = "01/01/2013";
    terminateDate = "<null>";

}

{

    activeFromDate = "01/01/2017";
    terminateDate = "02/05/2018";

}

{

    activeFromDate = "07/01/2012";
    terminateDate = "<null>";

}

{

    activeFromDate = "01/01/2017";
    terminateDate = "02/05/2019";

}
```

this is my code

```
 let answerArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0..<arr.count
    {
        let dict = Dictionary[i] as! NSDictionary
        let name1 = dict.value(forKey:"terminateDate") as! String
        if(name1 == "")
        {
            print (answerArray.add(dict))
        }
    }
```

this is my nsdictionary response 
how to get array count if terminatedDate is null and terminatedDate is greater than today date?

Comment: If you are using Swift3+, prefers Swift Dictionary and Array over NSDictionary and NSArray. Also, avoid using `value(forKey:)`, prefer `object(forKey:)`, you might have undesired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample to read json file placed in your project. and have integrated the code as per your requirement.

Json File

```
{"Status":"success","Data":[
    {"activeFromDate":"01/01/2017","terminateDate":"02/05/2019"},
    {"activeFromDate":"01/01/2013","terminateDate":null},
    {"activeFromDate":"01/01/2017","terminateDate":"02/05/2018"},
    {"activeFromDate":"07/01/2012","terminateDate":null},
    {"activeFromDate":"01/01/2017","terminateDate":"02/05/2016"},
    {"activeFromDate":"01/01/2017","terminateDate":"02/05/2019"}
]
}
```

In your View Controller

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

let answerArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    jsonParsingFromFile()
}


func jsonParsingFromFile()
{
    let path: NSString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tjw", ofType: "json")! as NSString
    let data : NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path as String, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMapped)
    self.startParsing(data: data)
}

func startParsing(data :NSData)
{
    let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? NSDictionary
    //print(dict)
    guard let dataArr:NSArray = dict.value(forKey: "Data") as? NSArray else {
        return
    }
    print(dataArr.count)
    for i in 0..<dataArr.count{
        guard let currentDict:NSDictionary = dataArr[i] as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }
        let activeFromDateStr:String = currentDict.value(forKey: "activeFromDate") as? String ?? ""
        let terminateDateStr:String = currentDict.value(forKey: "terminateDate") as? String ?? ""
        print(activeFromDateStr, terminateDateStr)
        if terminateDateStr != ""{
            let date2 = convertToDate(dateStr: terminateDateStr)
            let today = Date()
            if date2>today{
                answerArray.add(currentDict)
            }

        }else{
            answerArray.add(currentDict)
        }
    }
    print(answerArray)

}

func convertToDate(dateStr:String)->Date{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
    return date
}


}
```

Comment: let result = dictionary.filter { $0 ["terminateDate"]?.isEmpty == true } i am trying this but getting error  "Value of tuple type '(key: Any, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript' "